# The key in my B-Tree is not sorted, what's wrong?

Tags: c, b-tree, insertion

I have implemented my B-Tree starting to this struct:

```
#include <stdbool.h>  //(bool).
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  //( rand, srand).
#include <string.h>  // (strcmp)
#include <time.h>    //( time, clock()).

#define t 2
typedef struct BTreeNode {
  int key[t * 2];
  int n;
  bool leaf;
  struct BTreeNode* parent;
  struct BTreeNode* children[t * 2 + 1];
} BNode;

typedef struct {
  int cardinality;
  BNode* root;
} BTree;
```

After that I inserted the nodes through an insert algorithm, doing first a division of the children:

```
void BTreeSplitChild(BNode* x, int i) {
  BNode* y = x->children[i];
  BNode* z = (BNode*)malloc(sizeof(BNode));
  z->leaf = y->leaf;
  int j;
  for (j = 0; j < t - 1; j++)
    z->key[j] = y->key[j + t];
  if (y->leaf == false) {
    for (j = 0; j < t; j++)
      z->children[j] = y->children[j + t];
  }
  y->n = t - 1;
  for (j = x->n; j >=i + 1; j--) //
    x->children[j + 1] = x->children[j];
  x->children[i + 1] = z;
  for (j = x->n - 1; j >= i; j--) //
    x->key[j + 1] = x->key[j];
  x->key[i] = y->key[t];
  x->n += 1;
}
```

then the B-Tree-Insert-Nonfull procedure which inserts the key in a non-full node of the B-Tree:

```
void BTreeInsertNonFull(BNode* x, int key) {
  int i = x->n - 1;
  if (x->leaf == true) {
    while (i >= 0 && key < x->key[i]) {
      x->key[i + 1] = x->key[i];
      i--;
    }
    x->key[i + 1] = key;
    x->n += 1;
  } else {
    while (i >= 0 && key < x->key[i])
      i--;
    i++;
    if (x->children[i]->n == 2 * t - 1) {
      BTreeSplitChild(x, i);
      if (key > x->key[i])
        i++;
    }
    BTreeInsertNonFull(x->children[i], key);
  }
}
```

finally an insertion procedure that combines the two listed above:

```
void BTreeInsert(BTree* T, int key) {
  BNode* r = T->root;
  if (r->n == 2 * t - 1) {
    BNode* s = (BNode*)malloc(sizeof(BNode));
    T->root = s;
    s->leaf = false;
    s->n = 0;
    s->children[0] = r;
    BTreeSplitChild(s, 0);
    BTreeInsertNonFull(s, key);
  } else
    BTreeInsertNonFull(r, key);
}
```

but something went wrong as the keys contained within the nodes are not sorted :'(.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Why do you expect the keys within the node to be sorted? The core b-tree algorithm doesn't consider this aspect. It assumes that you'll figure it out yourself, or that you're happy with the keys within the node to be unsorted.

Comment: Well this algorithm should respect the rule that every key belonging to the left subtree of a node is of lower value than every key belonging to the subtree to its right or at least according to the pseudo-code I was inspired by. But through the debugger and with the help of an antagonist function I realized that this is not the case. But I can't understand where I went wrong.